# MongoDB: Write concern w:[number>1] - why?

Tags: mongodb

I'm trying to understand the advantages of using write concern  where  is greater than 1.

I understand the use cases for w:1, and w:primary.  I'm trying to understand why someone would use other values.  Let's use a 6-node (+arbiter) replica set as an example.

- If it's guaranteed writes with {w:majority, j:true} will survive the
  failure of the primary, what the advantage of the w:5?
- Does w:6 help to achieve linearizable access to secondaries at the
  expense of availability as a failure of any node will prevent writes?
  This is not documented as such.
- Why would someone ever use w:2 or w:3?  It doesn't guarantee the
  write will survive a failure of the primary.

Comment: Here is some useful documentation on Write Concern: https://docs.mongodb.com/v4.2/reference/write-concern/index.html

Answer (score 0):

Write concern is a mechanism for tuning availability, durability and performance.

In a w:1 environment, you essentially expect to lose data if the primary experiences any issue whatsoever.

In a w:2 environment, you still may lose data but you expect less loss because the data will be replicated. If you lose two nodes, and you are unlucky with where the second write went, you can lose the data.

In a w:3 environment, there is still potential for data loss but it is less than in the w:2 environment.

w:4 is majority write, a sensible default for most applications.

w:5 provides one "unnecessary" write. This means your writes will take longer than they would with w:majority but if you have elections, secondary nodes will generally be more up-to-date with the primary, so you would reduce election times.

w:6 writes to every node. If you are doing secondary reads and your nodes are geographically distributed, this is a way of getting the data to all of the nodes quicker at the expense of potential write unavailability and obviously longer writes.

> Does w:6 help to achieve linearizable access to secondaries at the expense of availability as a failure of any node will prevent writes?

No, this is not one of the benefits you get from w=# of nodes.

Comment: For w:2 or w:3, what does "less loss" mean?  Wouldn't only majority-confirmed writes survive primary failure, and if so writes that were not confirmed by majority, such as w:2/3 will be rolled back?

Comment: Not necessarily.

Comment: How so?  What does it depend on?

Comment: This is answered by Joe in your newest question.